# how to get the prepared statement query after binding

Tags: sql, logging, prepared-statement, log4j2

I am using the prepared statement like this

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = getConnection().prepareStatement(INSERT_QUERY);
        pstmt.setInt(1,userDetails.getUsersId());

log.debug("SQL for inserting child transactions " + pstmt.toString());
```

I want to log the exact SQL statement after binding into the log file but this thing is not working. It is logging it something like                 `SQLServerPreparedStatement:7`. I searched on internet but did not get the satisfactory answer. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This depends on the JDBC driver (and DBMS) being used. Some show the bind variables when `PreparedStatement.toString()` is called, some don't. If you have a driver which doesn't the only option you have, is to write a wrapper that captures the `setXXX()` methods and stores the parameter values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enable the JDBC internal logging by setting a PrintWriter on the DriverManager. Log4j2 provides an [IO Streams module](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-iostreams/index.html) so you can include the output in your normal log file. Sample code:

```
PrintWriter logger = IoBuilder.forLogger(DriverManager.class)
        .setLevel(Level.DEBUG)
        .buildPrintWriter();
DriverManager.setLogWriter(logger);
```

In addition, individual JDBC drivers often provide proprietary logging mechanisms, usually enabled with a system property. You will need to consult the documentation for your specific driver for the details.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a utility function which will replace the '?' with the bind variables.

Comment: I am looking for some generic answer Sir. This appears to be some work-around.